Can you solve all seven steps of my linguistic scavenger hunt?
Part 1:
The following text is written in an English cipher. Decode it. (You can use any online or digital decoders that you would like to use, but I will not disclose which type of cipher is used here.)
P jztth lzpl zpb xf offg jpo zfajtj, fxt fu lztd hrggsxv p ztpey opvfx, fxt mpaaysxv p qsv gfpb, pxb fxt mpaaysxv p dpx crsmkgy. Lzt jztth jpsb lf lzt zfajtj: "Dy ztpal hpsxj dt, jttsxv p dpx basesxv zfajtj." Lzt zfajtj jpsb: "Gsjltx, jztth, fra ztpalj hpsx rj oztx ot jtt lzsj: p dpx, lzt dpjlta, dpktj lzt offg fu lzt jztth sxlf p opad vpadtxl ufa zsdjtgu. Pxb lzt jztth zpj xf offg." Zpesxv ztpab lzsj, lzt jztth ugtb sxlf lzt hgpsx.
Part 2:
The following text printed in a certain script contains a transliterated paragraph in a language that does not use the script. Decrypt it and translate it to English.
ᘃᘙ ᘭᗴᘋᐧ ᗕᐣ ᙒᗕᘋᐧ ᗳᗬᐊᐧ ᘍᘃᐧ ᐟᗕᘦ ᘭᗴᑔᙑᐧ, ᘃᘙ ᙓᐣ ᙑ ᑎᘭᑓᐪᙚᗩᗔᑔᘦᔆ ᗕᐣ ᑔᘭᑓᗭᘆᑕᘣᐧᗲᐧ, ᘑᗴ ᘉᘅᗳ ᐟᗕᘦ ᘍ ᑔᘉᗔᗴᗴᐧ, ᘍ ᑔᘉᘭᙏᐧᘭᗴᐧ ᗕᐣ ᘍ ᑔᘉᘫᗭᘆᑕᗴᐧ.
Part 3:
The following text printed in Cyrillic contains a transliterated paragraph in a language that does not use the Cyrillic alphabet. Decrypt it and translate it to English.
Hint:

 The target language that the encrypted message is written in uses an abugida.

Њин жиґ ла, њин жиґ ла қйод раӈ наґс ҵал ду сbоӈ нас ґло бур ду раӈ њид кйи бсам ҵул чес. Қйэд кйис до снаӈ бйас паги бйа ба лаӈ по ни ћи жиґ йин. Ҷес шас ҷе ба ни қйод кйис қйод кйи клад паги наӈ ґи скад сґра шэс срид.
Part 4:
The following excerpt from a modern novel is written in Proto-Celtic. Decipher it.
Windeto Enderos rextums anwissoms katowom wirom onkus swexs blēdanyābos aiwestī. Bonnejetor bināti nāmantam talamoni ɸariwid gniyonti mīlā ed.
Tetēgee Enderos dū kolanei Stilsonī ɸlārei bibekʷe astnūs esyo tregete esyo.
Part 5:
The following two sentences are written in Proto-Turkic. Decipher them.
Hint:

 Proto-Turkic is also highly agglutinative and uses several suffixes to form nouns. Remember that several of these nouns are formed using suffixes plus case markings.

Kiši yaŋïlïĺ tüĺünükni kïrmaknï kǖsemeŕ. Ɨĺanuk sɨmtakniŋ edgü sēŕür.
Part 6:
Translate this following paragraph written in a Unicode encoding of Middle Egyptian hieroglyphs circa 1700 BCE to English. The text is written first from left to right and then from top to bottom, like in English.
Hint:

 Remember that the principles of Middle Egyptian spelling are very complex. Uniliteral and multiliteral signs are often used within the same text and several hieroglyphs are used only to indicate the context of the previous hieroglyph; there are also multiple ways to write the same word and inflection within the language. Furthermore, the plural forms of nouns end in -w, but they can be written by writing the singular form of the glyph three times in a row in addition to using a uniliteral sign for w or leaving the plural unmarked. Try creating a romanization of the text first and then breaking that down into smaller words to form the full text in romanized Egyptian; subsequently translate that to English. It would also help you to paste the hieroglyphs into a word processor because they appear very small on your screen.


Part 7:
Translate the following 13 Mayan glyphs shown on the following page that are ordered in the traditional block configuration to form a three sentence story. This text was created by me and is not found anywhere in the realm of Classic Maya literature.
Hint:

 Each Mayan glyph encodes a single word that is broken down into several (C)V phonetic subglyphs. However, the actual Classic Mayan syllable structure is (C)V(C). Research the nature of the script, drop the extra vowels used only in writing, transcribe the glottalized vowels correctly, and then obtain the actual text in Classic Maya. When translating the actual Classic Maya text, make sure to take note of prefixes and suffixes that are incorporated into words, which may consist of only a single consonant.


Prize:
The first person to correctly solve all seven steps can attach a text (of up to 200 English words) of your choosing. I will translate it into my conlang Pletavnä and include it as a comment. It will come with an IPA transcription and a gloss. I will accept any text as long as it is not religious, political, or offensive.

Posting seven unrelated puzzles in the same question isn't how this site works. People may answer different parts, may be correct for some and wrong for others, and then how do we vote on them? Could you perhaps ask one question per puzzle? They can still be linked to each other.

I will tell answerers which questions they got wrong, if they got some of them wrong.

That doesn't solve the issue of having multiple independent questions. Same issue as semi-interactive puzzles - the "correct" bits will end up being scattered across answers. Also, some people will only want to work on a subset of the puzzles. Posting individual puzzles allows answers, voting, and acceptance to be focused on a single puzzle.
